# Make Number of Rows Based on Column Values - Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to expand my data frame based on numeric values in two columns (`index_start` and `index_end`). My df looks like this:

```
item  index_start  index_end    
A          1            3
B          4            7
```

I want this to expand to create rows for A from 1 to 3 and rows for B from 4 to 7 like so.

```
item  index_start  index_end    index
A          1            3         1
A          1            3         2
A          1            3         3
B          4            7         4
B          4            7         5
B          4            7         6
B          4            7         7
```

Unsure how to implement this in Python/pandas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `.explode()`

```
df['index'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(range(row['index_start'], row['index_end']+1)), axis=1)
df.explode('index')

  item  index_start  index_end index
0    A            1          3     1
0    A            1          3     2
0    A            1          3     3
1    B            4          7     4
1    B            4          7     5
1    B            4          7     6
1    B            4          7     7
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`pd.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html#:%7E:text=Returns%20a%20new%20Index%20where,a%20given%20number%20of%20times.&text=The%20number%20of%20repetitions%20for,will%20return%20an%20empty%20Index.) with [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to repeat each of the elements `index_end - index_start + 1` times. Then generate the data between `index_start` and `index_end` using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap).

```
from itertools import starmap

rep = (df['index_end'] - df['index_start']) + 1
idx = df.index.repeat(rep)
vals = df.to_numpy()[:, 1:]
vals[:, 1] += 1
index = np.hstack([*starmap(np.arange, vals)])
df.reindex(idx).assign(index=index)

  item  index_start  index_end  index
0    A            1          3      1
0    A            1          3      2
0    A            1          3      3
1    B            4          7      4
1    B            4          7      5
1    B            4          7      6
1    B            4          7      7
```

[@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68926085/12416453) has nice readable solution but there are two bottleneck operations that would increase the runtime one is [`df.apply` over axis 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/12416453) and `df.explode`.

Timeit analysis:

Benchmarking setup:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
# @Ch3steR's solution
In [130]: %%timeit 
     ...: rep = (df['index_end'] - df['index_start']) + 1 
     ...: idx = df.index.repeat(rep) 
     ...: vals = df.to_numpy()[:, 1:] 
     ...: vals[:, 1] += 1 
     ...: index = np.hstack([*starmap(np.arange, vals)]) 
     ...: df.reindex(idx).assign(index=index) 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                       
4.82 ms ± 72.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# @Andreas' solution
In [131]: %%timeit 
     ...: df['index'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(range(row['index_start'], row[
     ...: 'index_end']+1)), axis=1) 
     ...: df.explode('index') 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                       
20.4 ms ± 796 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I ran tests a few times my solution is about ~4 times faster. We can further improve the speed if we could somehow `index = np.hstack([*starmap(np.arange, vals)])` vectorized this operation.

Comment: repeat / reindex is a neat solution. The performance vs readbility is also a good point.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you. Yeah readability over performance anyday. Given the readable solution isn't dragging you down. Great solution to you too.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, a small optimization on [Ch3steR's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68927699/13386979) is to create the `index` column by doing a groupby and taking a cumulative count of each group, and then offsetting the count by the `index_start`:

```
rep = (df['index_end'] - df['index_start']) + 1
res = df.loc[df.index.repeat(rep)]
res['index'] = res.groupby(res.index).cumcount() + res['index_start']
```

Output (`res`):

```
  item  index_start  index_end  index
0    A            1          3      1
0    A            1          3      2
0    A            1          3      3
1    B            4          7      4
1    B            4          7      5
1    B            4          7      6
1    B            4          7      7
```

And the timing, a la Ch3steR:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
rep = (df['index_end'] - df['index_start']) + 1
res = df.loc[df.index.repeat(rep)]
res['index'] = res.groupby(res.index).cumcount() + res['index_start']
# 1.66 ms ± 38.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

You'll have to trust that my timings for the other approaches are similar to what was posted : )

---

But to me, this feels like overkill for creating an index.  If the indices referenced in your original rows are always contiguous and non-overlapping (i.e. if one entry spans *i* to *j*, the next starts at *j + 1*), then `index` is just going to be a series of integers.  So creating it with a `range` should be correct:

```
res['index'] = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
```

Or maybe functionally-equivalently, you could just reset the DataFrame's index instead of creating `index`:

```
res = res.reset_index(drop=True)
```

It seems from your example input that this would be sufficient.  But the counter case would be if your `index_start` and `index_end` don't mean literal row numbers, and are more just used to compute how to repeat things.  So for example, if your data looked like so:

```
# now there are gaps in the indices, and it doesn't start at 1
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':['A','B'],
                   'index_start':[3, 5],
                   'index_end':[19, 22]})
```

But you still wanted the first row to be repeated 3 times and second one 4 times, AND you wanted to create that `index` column (in this case, `[3,4,5,19,20,21,22]`), you would need to do the groupby operation or something similar.

Comment: `groupby` + `cumcount` cool solution, should indeed be quicker than my solution.